# PyQt5: dynamically changing pseudo-classes

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

Disclaimer: I'm a relative newbie to Qt/PyQt5, so *any* advice would be welcome.

I am trying to correctly implement validation on a PyQt5 form, giving proper feedback to the user.

My current test code is:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing

from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QRegularExpression
from PyQt5.QtGui import QValidator, QRegularExpressionValidator
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout


class MyValidator(QRegularExpressionValidator):
    states = {
        QValidator.Invalid: 'invalid',
        QValidator.Intermediate: 'intermediate',
        QValidator.Acceptable: 'acceptable'
    }

    def validate(self, text: str, pos: int) -> typing.Tuple[QValidator.State, str, int]:
        def set_selector(s):
            p = self.parent()
            p.setProperty('selector', s)
            p.style().unpolish(p)
            p.style().polish(p)
            p.update()

        state, text, pos = super(MyValidator, self).validate(text, pos)
        selector = MyValidator.states[state]

        if selector == 'invalid':
            sel = self.parent().property('selector')
            QTimer.singleShot(1000, lambda: set_selector(sel))
        set_selector(selector)
        return state, text, pos


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.le = QLineEdit()
        regexp = QRegularExpression(r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}')
        self.le.setValidator(MyValidator(regexp, self.le))
        self.le.setProperty('selector', 'none')

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.le)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet('''\
    *[selector="invalid"] {border-radius: 3px; border: 1px solid red;}
    *[selector="intermediate"] {border-radius: 3px; border: 1px solid gold;}
    *[selector="acceptable"] {border-radius: 3px; border: 1px solid green;}
    ''')

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have three "problems" (IMHO strictly connected) with this code:

1. I would have liked to use pseudo-classes, but AFAIK thy are not supported by Qt5 (and thus PyQt5 supports them neither). Note that pseudo-classes, as pointed out by @ekhumoro, *are* supported, but they are implemented as a hard-coded (in c++) bitmap, so it's impossible to add "custom pseudo-classes" to handle something not currently implemented (e.g.: Validation).
2. In order to force stylesheet reevaluation I had to set a dummy stylesheet for the widget, which is both ugly and (more importantly!) it might break things if a local stylesheet is in use. This is strictly linked with next; see bottom Note2.
3. I am forced to completely redefine `QLineEdit` border because setting just `border-color: whatever;` is ignored. This, again, is both ugly and (more importantly!) wrong, because the re-created border is *not* exactly the same as the original one. This seems due to fact Qt does not use CSS "by default"; see bottom Note2.

Given the above question is: is this the correct way to implement visual feedback or is there some other (possibly cleaner) way?

Note: I understand this question has a certain amount of opinion-based facets, but I'm asking for consolidated "best practices", if available.

Note2: It seems (clarification from knowledgeable people welcome!) Qt does not use CSS by default. This is different from other languages/toolkits (e.g.: java/javaFX) where rendering is *always* driven by CSS and user "merely" updates/adds to the "default CSS" which actually exists.

My (possibly faulty) understanding is border (or any other graphic element) is "by default" drawn "by hand" (in c++, drawing directly on canvas), while *IFF* user defines a *relevant* CSS element a separate rendering engine is called and thus rendering is potentially different.

In the specific case of "border" I was unable to correctly define a CSS border identical to the "default" drawing; as you can see running the snippet it draws a border that's one pixel *inside* the default one; I have not been able to "fix" it.

I am quite happy with the code above, but any "Answer" deepening my understanding of QWidget interaction with CSS and related issues will be gladly accepted.

### Update:

As @ekhumoro pointed out in a comment, I'm not using the Qt-approved syntax for [Dynamic Properties](https://wiki.qt.io/Dynamic_Properties_and_Stylesheets).
Two notes on that:

1. Using `style().polish()` actually solves my problem with vertical border dimension.
2. Using `style().unpolish()` / `style().polish()` like in my revised code above does *not* work as expected... partially. It actually works ok for "static" borders (`Intermediate` and `Acceptable` Validator statuses) but does not work well for "transient" (`Invalid`) borders.

Any insight welcome.

### Update2:

I updated code snippet to the final (fully working) version following @ekhumoro (MANY thanks!) advice.

Problem, for me, is solved. I will leave the Question open for future reference.

Comment: (1) QSS actually relies quite heavily on [pseudo-states](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-pseudo-states). (2) See [Dynamic Properties and Stylesheets](https://wiki.qt.io/Dynamic_Properties_and_Stylesheets). (3) It would be much more straightforward to change the background colour of the text field, since there's no way to know what kind of border (if any) the user's widget style will display. If you don't use a stylesheet, you'll have to reimplement the line-edit's [paintEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent).

Comment: @ekhumoro: (1) Yes, I know, but they are implemented as a hard-coded bitmap and thus it's not possible to add custom pseudo-states; that would have been the cleanest solution (IMHO). (2) Yes, that's what I'm using in the snippet (I'll update it to my latest). (3) That has little to do with the problem at hand: *what* to change should be defined in CSS and, possibly, changed dynamically "just" editing a global stylesheet (I will edit OP to reflect my findings).

Comment: (1) Dynamic properties are effectively custom pseudo-states. (2) No, you're not. Read the last section of that article. (3) What problem? Why should the user care about a trivial colour change that lasts for one second? (0) If you want more information, please consult the extensive [Qt Style Sheets Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html).

Comment: Thanks for Your comments. (1) agreed. (2) Please have a look to my revised code; if You can divine why the `Invalid` case is misbehaving... (3) IMHO the "trivial color change is a symptom I'm not doing things right and that's the reason I try to get to the bottom of it; actually it seems using `polish()` is the right solution (If I can make it work).  (0) Yesss! I already skimmed through it, but I'll study it deeper. If You can find an Answer to the remaining problem please write it and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: (2) Appending the line `p.update()` seems to work.